# Postgres deadlock in INSERT VALUES concurrent with ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I create tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tgroups (
    group_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    vacancy_id text
);
CREATE INDEX tgroups_vacancy_id_idx ON tgroups (vacancy_id);

CREATE TABLE tscores (
    application_id text NOT NULL,
    group_id text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tscores_pkey PRIMARY KEY (application_id, group_id),
    CONSTRAINT tscores_group_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES tgroups(group_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX tscores_group_id_idx ON tscores(group_id);
```

I then have two processes executing SQL transactions in very rapid succession. Both have the standard READ COMMITTED isolation level. The first process is running this, except the values in the `INSERT...VALUES` are in a random order (I've done it in Python):

```
BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM tgroups WHERE vacancy_id = 'vacancy1';

    INSERT INTO tgroups (group_id, vacancy_id) VALUES
    ('group1', 'vacancy1'),
    ('group2', 'vacancy1'),
    ...
    ('group10', 'vacancy1');
COMMIT;
```

The second process runs the following SQL. Again, the values in `INSERT...VALUES` are in a random order. The variable :application_id is chosen from the set ["application1"..."application10"], which I've done with Python (I guess you could achieve the same in pgsql):

```
BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM tscores WHERE application_id = :application_id;

    INSERT INTO tscores (application_id, group_id) VALUES
    (:application_id, 'group1'),
    (:application_id, 'group2'),
    ...
    (:application_id, 'group10');
COMMIT;
```

This sometimes deadlocks:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError) deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 527 waits for ShareLock on transaction 391860; blocked by process 526.
Process 526 waits for ShareLock on transaction 391861; blocked by process 527.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while deleting tuple (2,218) in relation "tgroups"
 [SQL: "DELETE FROM tgroups WHERE vacancy_id = 'vacancy1';"]
```

I can only reproduce the deadlock if both of the following are true:

1. The deletes in tscores from the first transaction are carried out behind the scenes by `ON DELETE CASCADE`. If I remove the constraint and manually delete the rows in question at the beginning of the transaction there is no deadlock
2. The values inside the insert statement are in a random order

I was under the impression that both `DELETE` and `INSERT...VALUES` were atomic, and that `ON DELETE CASCADE` happened at the same time as the DELETE it is related to. Therefore I'd have thought that if one transaction was already in process, the blocked transaction would block on `DELETE` until the other transaction finished, and then continue, and indeed this is what seems to happen if I manually run the two transactions line-by-line in separate psql sessions.

Somehow I clearly misunderstand the way that locks, inserts, foreign keys and cascades interact.

NB I am aware sometimes the `INSERT` into tscores will sometimes fail because the group that is referenced has just been deleted, but this isn't my problem (though I guess it could be related).

Answer (score 2):

I would not worry about the behavior, just retry the transaction if terminated by the deadlock.

The first transaction tries to delete A and B, and acquires sequentially a lock on them, and the second deletes B and A, with the same approach. Upon locking A and B, none of the two transactions can progress, hence one of them is terminated by a deadlock.